# To read a key using item with Dictionay code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I'm in the middle of writing some line of code at Excel VBA.
Testing "Dictionray", got an Error.

My goal is pretty simle, I'd like to read "a" using "one".
What did I wrong ?

```
Dim myDictionary
Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
myDictionary("a") = "one"
MsgBox myDictionary("a")         ' works Fine
MsgBox myDictionary.Key("one")   ' emits Error
```

Comment: Do `myDictionary("a") = "one" : myDictionary("b") = "one" : myDictionary("c") = "one"`. Now what should `myDictionary.Key("one")` return?

Comment: You can search the dictionary by key, but not by value. The key of your entry is `"a"`, so you can find `myDictionary("a")` but not `myDictionary.Key("one")`. If you really need to look the other way around, create a 2nd dictionary with interchanged keys and values.

Comment: The Key method of the scripting.dictionary allows you to change the key.  It does not provide access to the Item associated with the key.  You will need to do a linear search of the Items array to find the first occurrence of "one" and then use the index to get the key from the .Keys array. A second dictionary may work as it depends on the items also being unique.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks you !!! so, in short, I had a dream not possible. OK. I give it up... Now I'm in the land of calm. Thanks again.

Comment: @FunThomas You too

Comment: @freeflw And You too, of course.

Comment: Is there any way to wrap up this question ? I am not familiar with some kind of Policies...